# Fitting parabola to data set using inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to find $P(x) = ax^2 +bx + c$ that fits the following data set:
$$P(1) = 2\\P(2) = 3\\P(3) = 4$$

using the least squares method. That is, we need to minimize

$$\min \sum_{i=0}^2 (y_i -(ax_i^2 + bx_i + c))^2$$

**I don't know how but somehow, using polynomial projections I can see that**

$$\langle y-(ax^2 + bc + c), 1\rangle = 0\\\langle y-(ax^2 + bc + c), x\rangle = 0\\\langle y-(ax^2 + bc + c), x^2\rangle = 0$$

**can anyone explain me this part?**

which leads us to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \langle x^2,1\rangle & \langle x,1\rangle & \langle 1,1\rangle\\
    \langle x^2,x\rangle & \langle x,x\rangle & \langle 1,x\rangle \\
    \langle x^2,x^2\rangle & \langle x,x^2\rangle & \langle 1,x^2\rangle
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\langle y,1 \rangle\\\langle y,x \rangle\\\langle y,x^2 \rangle\end{bmatrix}$$

If we use the inner product:

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^2f_i g_i$$

we end up with

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    14 & 6 & 3\\36 & 14 & 6 \\ 98 & 36 & 14
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}9 \\ 20 \\ 50\end{bmatrix}$$

[which leads to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B14,6,3%7D,%7B36,14,6%7D,%7B98,36,14%7D%7D*%7B%7Ba%7D,%7Bb%7D,%7Bc%7D%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7B9%7D,%7B20%7D,%7B50%7D%7D) $a=0,b=1,c=1$ which is not the polynomial I wanted.

**Attention: please do not use derivatives and equate to $0$, I need to solve this using projections and inner products**

Comment: Why wouldn't that be the correct answer? It fits the data perfectly! You won't be able to find a solution where $a \not= 0$ because a best fit occurs when $a=0$. You'd no longer be fitting a curve to data, because you've already found a curve that does fit the data.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley oops, you're rigth. Could you explain to me the reasoning of why the inner products must be zero?